# both if and else statements are executed in Stata

Tags: if-statement, stata

Both if and else statements are executed when "`md'"=="lowess". Could anyone please explain how in the world this is possible?!

```
loc methods "connected lowess"

foreach md in `methods' {
if "`md'"=="lowess" {
    di "`md'==lowess"
}
else
{
    di "`md'!=lowess"
}
}
```

The output is:

```
. do "/tmp/SD11749.000000"

. loc methods "connected lowess"

. 
. foreach md in `methods' {
  2.         if "`md'"=="lowess" {
  3.                 di "`md'==lowess"
  4.         }
  5.         else
  6.         {
  7.                 di "`md'!=lowess"
  8.         }
  9. }       
connected!=lowess
lowess==lowess
lowess!=lowess
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `else` and the subsequent `{` must be on the same line

Comment: @Nick Cox - I would argue that `else` and `{` are atomic and therefore need not be joined grammatically by an `its` :) It is indeed a possessive, but .....

Comment: Not clear on your point; your original "it's", meaning "it is", would make no sense there. I edited "its" to "the" to avoid any issue.